# How do I use children() correctly to find name and id of input field?

Tags: jquery

Here an example

```
$newattribute.children("div").children("input,select").each(function (i) {
    var $currentElem = $(this);
    $currentElem.attr("name", $currentElem.attr("name") + current);
    $currentElem.attr("id", $currentElem.attr("id") + current);
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><select id="attribute_name" name="attribute_name">
          <option value="1">Size</option>
          <option value="2">Color</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="attribute_value" name="attribute_value"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="attribute_qty" name="attribute_qty"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="attribute_price" name="attribute_price"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

How do I use `.children("div")` correctly to find `name` & `id`?

Comment: say what? what do you mean "correctly find..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.children()` because it finds, well, children. As in, not grandchildren, not great-grandchildren, just immediate children. To find *descendants* use `.find()`. So:

```
$newattribute.children("div").find("input,select")
```

You don't say what `$newattribute` is, but assuming it is the immediate parent of the div element shown in the question then the statement I just showed will find all input and select elements that are descendants of that div.

The [API doco for `.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) explains this further, and links to the [doco for `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).